# Merge two array of objects into one by given key and duplicating other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects that contain similar values

```
data = [array1, array2]

array1 = [{hour: "565", age: "21", id: "1", naban: "sdfsd"}, {hour: "515", age: "25", id: "2", naban: "sf"}]
array2 = [{hour: "56454", age: "21", id: "1", too: "898"}, {hour: "8979", age: "25", id: "2", too: "234234"},  {hour: "65465", age: "27", id: "6", too: "123"}]
```

and I have an array of which values of those two object set will be used for merge

```
keys= ['id', 'id']
```

I want to merge those objects and create one array of objects shown below:

```
result = [{hour: "565", hour2: "56454", age: "21", age2: "21", id: "1", too: "898", naban: "sdfsd"}, {hour: "515", hour2: "8979", age: "25", age2: "25", id: "2", too: "234234", naban: "sf"}, {hour: "65465", age: "27", id: "6", too: "123"} ]
```

Criteria:

- Id like to keep all the information that is not in the keys array eg. if you look at the result array you will see hour and hour2 values.
- If keys don't match it will push the object as it is (eg. 3rd item in the result array)

This is what I did so far:

```
mergeOjects = (object, keys) => {
const sameKeys = Object.values(keys);
const data = Object.values(object);

if (data[0].length > data[1].length) {
  const yarrak = data[0].map((item, i) => {
    if (item[sameKeys[0]] === data[1][i][sameKeys[1]]) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, data[1][i]);
    }
    return Object.assign({}, item);
  });
  console.log({ sameKeys, data, yarrak });
} else {
  const yarrak = data[1].map((item, i) => {
    if (data[0][i]) {
      if (item[sameKeys[1]] === data[0][i][sameKeys[0]]) {
        return Object.assign({}, item, data[0][i]);
      }
    }
    return Object.assign({}, item);
  });
  console.log({ sameKeys, data, yarrak });
}};
```

it may need a bit of cleaning but I'm trying to get the logic work now, so sorry in advance.
I was able to complete the second criteria but it overwrites the hour value instead of storing separately as it is in the example

Comment: Can include a minimal working code?

Comment: why do you have two `hour` but only one `age`? because of the different values?

Comment: I don't have a working solution yet. last code snipped is farthest I came

Comment: I missed the age, you are right it should be age2 as well

Comment: @NinaScholz fixed. sorry

Comment: why do you have a `keys` array, how should it be if the keys are different? what should happen? i would understand if the group has more than one key, but if the same, the array makes no sense.

Comment: purpose of the key array is to tell the app, which fields are going to be used as the same keys. I am trying to merge two datasets and not always it comes with same name keys as in the example (which are 'id's). So the user first chooses which keys will match. for example, it might be the id from the first array of objects and age from the second array of objects have the same values

Comment: it works only if you have just two arrays. by having more, the merged array has no reak onbly key anymore for comapiring.

Comment: const sameKeys = Object.values(keys);
const data = Object.values(object);     ////  they turned into array in the function. But in the app it will be 2 datasets always. and the order of them will be the same as well. ( but you are right its not the best way to match them )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the second array and take the wanted keys as common part for look up.

```js
var array1 = [{ hour: "565", age: "21", id: "1", naban: "sdfsd" }, { hour: "515", age: "25", id: "2", naban: "sf" }],
    array2 = [{ hour: "56454", age: "21", id: "1", too: "898" }, { hour: "8979", age: "25", id: "2", too: "234234" }, { hour: "65465", age: "27", id: "6", too: "123" }],
    data = [array1, array2],
    keys = ['id', 'id'],
    merged = data[1].reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(q => o[keys[0]] === q[keys[1]]);
        if (temp) {
            Object
                .entries(o)
                .forEach(([k, v]) => {
                    if (keys.includes(k)) return;
                    temp[k in temp ? k + 2 : k] = v;
                });
        } else {
            r.push({ ...o });
        }
        return r;
    }, data[0]);

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```